# Facebook login button not rendring in thickbox

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp-1.3

I am working with cakephp 1.3

And I integrating face-book login button with cakephp.

I take code of facebook-login-button code from website and include it in my cakephp layout.

It show facebook-login-button on my home page.

But it facebook-login-button not show in my thickbox.

actually i want to render facebook-login-button multiple time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to re-initialize it, as the facebook javascript framework rendered the pages buttons before the thickbox was generated.

In the callback for thickbox (onComplete?) just call the `FB.init()` function again.

Forgive me if any of the function names are incorrect, it has been a while since I used the FB framework.

Comment: first thanks for your response. how I FB.init() call it again.

Comment: Do it the same way you call init() on your main page.

Answer (score 2):

try to call

```
window.fb_sharepro_render();
```